# replacing 'pi' with '3.14' in a string recursively [test cases not passed]

Tags: python-3.x, string, recursion

'I searched in the forum but it provided the answer in java not in Python'

I tried to make a function that takes one argument and replaces 'pi' with '3.14' in a string recursively.Here is my code:

```
def changePi(s):
  if 'pi' not in s:
    return s

  else:
    return changePi(s.replace('pi','3.14',1))
```

Is my code right? 
My code is returning the correct output but when checked with test cases no output is received.I executed this code to check the test cases after passing the above code:

```
assert changePi("pixyzpi") == "3.14xyz3.14"
assert changePi("pixypiabpi") == "3.14xy3.14ab3.14"
```

Comment: Why do you need a recursion when `replace` can replace every occurence at once?

Comment: I am supposed to write a recursive function.Is there any method I can do this recursively without using ```replace```

Comment: ..in which case you should not be using built-in functions.

Comment: I can use built in function as long as the code is recursive and loops are not used

Comment: "no output is received" - that's good, `assert` is supposed to raise an exception only when check has failed. Thus no output -> all tests have passed

Comment: @R2RTYeah I got it .Guess my code is right.